# How to create dynamic ng-model identifier?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to create the scope identifier dynamically?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filters">
        {{key}}<br/><input ng-model="filters.value" type="text">
    </li>
</ul>
```

That is what i will create:

```
name <input type="text" ng-model="filters.name">
role <input type="text" ng-model="filters.role">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.filters = {name: "user", role:"user"};
```

I need this format to use in for filter ng-repeat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filters">
  {{key}}<br/><input ng-model="filters[key]" type="text">
</li>
```

`filters[key]` allows you to access a field in `filters` using a dynamic field name.